# Enabling the "setgrid" option for a Tkinter widget

Tags: python, tkinter, gridlayoutmanager

I am using the `grid` geometry manager of Tkinter to generate a table with horizontally scrollable text in column 2. I tried creating a `Listbox` widget that lives in column 2 (as a child of the overall frame) and spans all the rows. This seemed promising, until it became apparent that the lines of text in the Listbox are not aligned with the rows of the parent grid. I've been searching in vain for a way to pad each row of text in the Listbox so that the rows match up; but even if that were possible, I would prefer a more general, less kludgy solution.

I recently stumbled across a [description](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/wm.htm) of Gridded Geometry Management that alludes to a setgrid option for a widget. It purports to do exactly what I want: that is, "[determine] whether this widget controls the resizing grid for its top-level window." I tried enabling this option in my `Listbox` widget, but to no avail. Am I somehow misunderstanding the purpose/usage of setgrid?

(In order to see the problem with the code below, use the `Select File` or `Select Folder` buttons to load multiple audio files into the file list.)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

#################################################
# This tool allows the user to select audio files 
# (or folders containing audio files) and subject 
# them to loudness analysis.
#################################################

import sys
import os
import codecs
import re
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
from os import walk
from os import path
from Tkinter import Tk, Text, BOTH, W, N, E, S
from ttk import Frame, Button, Label, Style, Progressbar
from ScrolledText import *
from progressbar import ProgressBar

class Leveler_tk(Frame):
    fileList = []
    allowedExtensions = ['mp3','mp2','m4a','aiff','wav']

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(2, pad=250)
        self.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)

        lbl1 = Label(self, text="Analyze")
        lbl1.grid(pady=4, padx=5,row=0,column=0)

        lbl2 = Label(self, text="Adjust")
        lbl2.grid(pady=4, padx=5,row=0,column=1)

        lbl3 = Label(self, text="File")
        lbl3.grid(pady=4, padx=5,row=0,column=2)

        lbl4 = Label(self, text="Integrated\nLoudness")
        lbl4.grid(pady=4, padx=5,row=0,column=3)

        lbl5 = Label(self, text="LRA")
        lbl5.grid(pady=4, padx=5,row=0,column=4)

        lbl6 = Label(self, text="Peak")
        lbl6.grid(pady=4, padx=5,row=0,column=5)

        lbl7 = Label(self, text="Progress")
        lbl7.grid(pady=4, padx=5,row=0,column=6)

        lbl8 = Label(self, text="Meets\nSpecs?")
        lbl8.grid(sticky=W, pady=4, padx=5,row=0,column=7)

        file_btn = Button(self, text="Select File",command=self.selectFile)
        file_btn.grid(row=1,rowspan=2, column=8,padx=5,pady=4)

        folder_btn = Button(self, text="Select Folder", command=self.selectFolder)
        folder_btn.grid(row=3, rowspan=2, column=8,padx=5,pady=4)

    def render(self):
        count = 0
        filebox = Listbox(self,selectmode=EXTENDED,setgrid=1)
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(filebox, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        scrollbar.config(command=filebox.xview)
        filebox.grid(row=1, column=2, rowspan=len(self.fileList), columnspan=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        filebox.config(xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        scrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        for file in self.fileList:
            analyze = IntVar()
            adjust = IntVar()
            Radiobutton(self, text="", variable=analyze, value=count, borderwidth=0).grid(row=count+1, column=0)
            Radiobutton(self, text="", variable=adjust,  value=count, borderwidth=0).grid(row=count+1, column=1)
            filebox.insert(END, file + "\n")
            Progressbar(self, orient=HORIZONTAL,length=100, mode='determinate').grid(row=count+1, column=6)
            count += 1

    def addToList(self, name):
        dot = re.search("\.(?=[^.]*$)",name)
        extension = name[dot.end():]
        if extension in self.allowedExtensions and not name in self.fileList:
            self.fileList.append(name)

    def selectFile(self):
        input = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = [('MP3', '*.mp3'), ('MP2', '*.mp2'), ('M4A', '*.m4a'), ('AIFF', '*.aiff'), ('WAV', '*.wav')], multiple = 1)
        for el in input:
            if os.path.isfile(el) and ".DS_Store" not in el:
                try:
                    self.addToList(el)
                except:
                    tkMessageBox.showerror("Some error")
        self.render()

    def selectFolder(self):
        input = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
        for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(input):
            for name in filenames:
                if name != ".DS_Store":
                    self.addToList(dirpath + "/" + name)
        self.render()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Leveler_tk(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding `setgrid`.

It is so that a widget with a natural size that is based on something other than a pixel (such as a text widget, whose size is based on characters) can prevent the parent from setting it to an unnatural size (eg: 20.5 characters). With `setgrid`, when you interactively resize the window it will resize in grid units (eg: character height or width) rather than pixels.

`setgrid` doesn't prevent resizing so much as that it makes sure resizing happens at multiples of some other unit.

Here is the complete, definitive reference for the `setgrid` option, from the tcl/tk manual:

> Specifies a boolean value that determines whether this widget controls
>   the resizing grid for its top-level window. This option is typically
>   used in text widgets, where the information in the widget has a
>   natural size (the size of a character) and it makes sense for the
>   window's dimensions to be integral numbers of these units. These
>   natural window sizes form a grid. If the setGrid option is set to true
>   then the widget will communicate with the window manager so that when
>   the user interactively resizes the top-level window that contains the
>   widget, the dimensions of the window will be displayed to the user in
>   grid units and the window size will be
>   constrained to integral numbers of grid units. See the section GRIDDED
>   GEOMETRY MANAGEMENT in the wm manual entry for more details.

Comment: Thanks very much Bryan; I appreciate your clarification of `setgrid`, I was definitely barking up the wrong tree. Do you happen to know of any way to make a single column horizontally scrollable while preserving its alignment with the other rows in the grid?